# Fastest way of finding the location of the first integer in a string

Tags: groovy

I'm reading lines from a text file that look like this:

```
 ;Nonsense/sec;0.17;0;0.13;0.05;0.07;0.2;0.1;0.12;0.1;0.05;
 ;Foo/bar;0.17;0;0.13;0.05;0.07;0.2;0.1;0.12;0.1;0.05;
 ;Coding errors;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;
```

What I need to do is find the location of the first number in any given line so that I can do something like this:

```
 line = line.substring(firstIntegerLocation, line.length())
```

Instead of hardcoding the starting location like so:

```
 line = line.substring(10, line.length()-2)
```

Every line begins with some text, separated by semicolons then a series of numbers, the numbers is what I'm after. I need to ignore the alphabetic characters (and any special characters like a slash) in the begining.

I have to use Java 7, not 8 so any solution has to be old :) I need a simple method that I can pass the string to, then it would return the location of the first integer. I'm looking for the fastest way of doing this as I have a lot of lines to process, and again with Java 7, not 8. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use regular expression:

```groovy
def line = ';Nonsense/sec;0.17;0;0.13;0.05;0.07;0.2;0.1;0.12;0.1;0.05;'
line = line.replaceAll( /^\D*/, '' )
```

this replaces all non-digits `\D*` at the beginning of line `^` with empty string.

---

however if you are going to work later with numbers there is a way to get array of numbers:

```groovy
def line = ';Nonsense/sec;0.17;0;0.13;0.05;0.07;0.2;0.1;0.12;0.1;0.05;'
def nums = line.findAll(/(\d+(\.\d+)?)/).collect{it as BigDecimal}
```

returns:

```
[0.17, 0, 0.13, 0.05, 0.07, 0.2, 0.1, 0.12, 0.1, 0.05]
```

Comment: One thing I noticed about this is it dissects the floatinjg point numbers so that's not going to work for me.